# How to know overall code coverage of multiple test classes?

Tags: unit-testing, salesforce, apex

I have a class having multiple test classes and I want to know the overall code coverage of the class. How can I know that?

Answer (score 0):

First you should run all the needed test from either Developer Console or Setup:

- Developer Console: Open *Test* menu then click on *New Run* then select multiple classes and click **Add Selected**.
- Setup: type `Apex Test Execution` in quick search and click on it.
  Click **Select Tests...**, then select multiple classes and click **Run**.

Once every test method has been executed, you can open the class that has been tested in the Developer Console (File > Open Resource) then click on **Code Coverage** (next to *API Version*) and select **All Tests**.